# set a css class of element in partial from outside

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

For example, I have a page with this content:

```
<div>
    Some web page
    <partial name="Path/To/Partial.cshtml" class="css-class-to-#ID-1" model="@SomeModel"/>
</div>
```

And I have a partial view with this content:

```
<div id="ID-1" class="I-want-the-css-class-here">
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

I know I could pass the css class through the model, but that would complicate the passing of other data, requiring for example wrapper classes.

The assumption would be, that I always have only one parent html element in the partial.

My question is: How could one achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session to store the class：

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
       ...
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("class", "css-class-to-#ID-1");
}
<div>
    Some web page
    <partial name="Path/To/Partial.cshtml" model="@SomeModel"/>
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
<div id="ID-1" class=@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("class")>
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```